# How to bridge rows in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

This question is similar to one [I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222443/how-to-create-a-column-that-is-stretched-over-two-rows), but this time I am trying to achieve the layout using a different approach: grids, not block-grids.

I read ZURB's article on [How to bridge rows in Foundation](http://zurb.com/university/library/1), but the end result deviates from my expectation. There is no margin between the first and the second row. So how do I get that margin to work, that you see in the [picture](https://s3.amazonaws.com/university-prod/uploads/attachments/5/original/teaser.png?1375124186) at the article?

This is what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/NPUHy/

**First approach**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-9 small-centered column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 column">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/256x512&text=PANEL"/>
            </div>
            <div class="small-8 column">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-6 column">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-6 column">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-6 column">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-6 column">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Second Approach**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-9 small-centered column">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/256x512&text=PANEL"/>
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="small-4 columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="small-12 columns">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/256&text=ROW-2"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the question? what are you trying to acheive

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was clear. "There is no padding between the first and the second row." I need that padding. I will rewrite post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class to the row div`<div class="row custom">`, and then add a padding to the class

```
.row .custom {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NPUHy/1/

Comment: Are you sure this is the right answer? I was under the impression that there should be a margin/padding by default? Do I really need to add that myself?

Comment: rows in foundation do not have spaces between them. no margin or no padding. If you need space you have to write a custom class!